# Compare Lead Statecode field to Custom setting Statecode and update a field on Lead with the Region

Tags: apex, batch, customsetting

I have a custom setting name "StateAbbreviationsInfo" which has fields of Statecode__c and Region__C.
The requirement is to create a batch class and check for the lead statecode and find the appropriate Region from the custom setting and update it on the Owner_Division_Region__c  on lead.

```
global class UpdateRegion implements Database.Batchable<SObject> , Database.Stateful,Schedulable {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

     Set<Id> lset = new Set<Id>();
     lset.add(Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ABC').getRecordTypeId());
     string query ='Select id,name,Owner_Division_Region__c from Lead where RecordTypeId IN :lset';
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> Scope){
   Map<String,StateAbbreviations__c> stateabb = StateAbbreviations__c.getAll();
   List<Lead> listToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
   for(Lead ld : (Lead[]) Scope){
   if(ld.id!=null){

   if(StateAbbreviations__c.containsKey(Lead.Statecode))
   {
   ld.Owner_Division_Region__c = stateabb.get(Statecode).Region__c;
   listToUpdate.add(Id);

   }

  }

  }
    if(listToUpdate.size() > 0){
    Database.Update(listToUpdate);
    }
   }
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        database.executeBatch(new UpdateRegion());
   }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal please see the above code. I am positive that my assignment is not right

Comment: Is this the correct code, does this compile? I see `listToUpdate.add(<i in UPPER CASE>d);`, is that a typo and that it should be `listToUpdate.add(<L in LOWER CASE>d);` instead?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal im seeing the following compile error : Error: Compile Error: Class UpdateRegion must implement the method: System.Iterable<Lead> Database.Batchable<Lead>.start(Database.BatchableContext) at line 1 column 14

Comment: It should be <sObject?>

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I did update the code. But Still showing:  Variable does not exist: Statecode at line 19 column 47

Comment: do you have statecode field in your lead?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal StateCode is a standard field on lead .

Comment: :( Try again now. :(

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thankyou it is working. I had to check for state instead of Statecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in line

`if(StateAbbreviations__c.containsKey(Lead.Statecode))`

You already made a map of String vs `StateAbbreviations__c` above as `Map<String,StateAbbreviations__c> stateabb` . You have to use contains in it.

Secondly,`Lead.Statecode` is a field token, not the actual value of lead's Statecode. To get actual value of lead's statecode you have to use ld.Statecode

As you are using statecode field , you have to include that in your SOQL as well.

```
global class UpdateRegion implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

     Set<Id> lset = new Set<Id>();
     lset.add(Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ABC').getRecordTypeId());
     string query ='Select id,name,Owner_Division_Region__c , Statecode from Lead where RecordTypeId IN :lset';
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> leadList){
        Map<String,StateAbbreviations__c> stateabb = StateAbbreviations__c.getAll();
        List<Lead> listToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
        for(Lead ld : leadList){

               if(stateabb.containsKey(ld.Statecode)){
                ld.Owner_Division_Region__c = stateabb.get(ld.Statecode).Region__c;
                listToUpdate.add(ld);
            }

        }
        if(listToUpdate.size() > 0){
            Database.Update(listToUpdate);
        }
   }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```